# printw() won't print a single character from a uint8_t array

Tags: c, ncurses, curses, pdcurses

Here is my main() code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#ifdef __gnu_linux__
    #include <ncurses.h>
#endif
#ifdef _WIN32
    #include <curses.h>
#endif
#include "terminal_info.h"
#include "interface.h"
int main()
{
    initscr();
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    testForUI();
    readUIFile();
    continuouslyUpdateInfo();
    refresh();
    printDocument();
    getch();
    endwin();
    clearAll();
    return 0;
}
```

The problem I'm having occurs in `printDocument()`:

```
void printDocument()
{
    int counter = 0;
    printw("Document Size: %d\n", documentSize);
    for(counter = 0; counter < documentSize; counter++)
    {
        printw("%c",(char)document[counter]);
        refresh();
    }

}
```

At the start of the for loop, gdb says the contents of document are as follows:

```
$1 = (uint8_t *) 0x3e32c0 "<Root>\r\n    <Hello>World</Hello>\r\n    <This>\r\n
<Is>:-)</Is>\r\n        <An>:-O</An>\r\n        <Example>:-D</Example>\r\n    </This>\r\n</Root>\r\n««««««««_î_î_"
```

But the program only prints:

```
Document Size: 123
```

However, if I change the printw statement to:

```
printw("%c - %d",(char)document[counter], document[counter]);
```

I get this:

```
Document Size: 123

 - 13
 - 10  - 32  - 32  - 32  - 32< - 60H - 72e - 101l - 108l - 108o - 111> - 62W - 8
7o - 111r - 114l - 108d - 100< - 60/ - 47H - 72e - 101l - 108l - 108o - 111> - 6
 - 13
 - 13
 - 10    - 9< - 60I - 73s - 115> - 62: - 58- - 45) - 41< - 60/ - 47I - 73s - 115
 - 13
 - 10    - 9< - 60A - 65n - 110> - 62: - 58- - 45O - 79< - 60/ - 47A - 65n - 110
 - 13
 - 10    - 9< - 60E - 69x - 120a - 97m - 109p - 112l - 108e - 101> - 62: - 58- -
 - 13
 - 13
 - 13
 - 10
```

I tried disabling buffering in main() with setvbuf(), but it hasn't done me any good at all.

Here is the document that is read and printed, if it may help:

```
<Root>
    <Hello>World</Hello>
    <This>
    <Is>:-)</Is>
    <An>:-O</An>
    <Example>:-D</Example>
    </This>
</Root>
```

Declaration of document: `extern uint8_t * document;`

Comment: Post declaration of `document[]`.

Comment: Maybe add `fflush(stdout)` after `printw("%c",(char)document[counter]);`

Comment: @chux Posted the declaration and `fflush(stdout)` hasn't done a thing :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get rid of the carriage return (CR) characters (`\r`).

When you output a CR, ncurses resets the cursor to the first column in the same row. Then when you output a NL (`\n`), ncurses erases from the cursor position to the end of the row before advancing the cursor to the next row. That effectively deletes the entire row that was just printed.

This behaviour is documented, for what it's worth. From `man waddch` (emphasis added):

> If `ch` is a tab, newline, or backspace, the cursor is moved appropriately within the window.  Backspace moves  the  cursor  one  character left; at the left edge of a window it does nothing.  **Newline does a `clrtoeol`**, then moves the cursor to the window left margin on the next line, scrolling the window if on the last line.  Tabs are considered to be at every eighth column.  The tab interval may  be  altered  by setting the `TABSIZE` variable.

The response to a carriage return is documented in the ncurses waddch manpage, at the end of the PORTABILITY section:

> If  `ch`  is  a  carriage return, the cursor is moved to the       beginning of the current row of the window. This is  true of other implementations, but is not documented.

(Thanks to Thomas Dickey for pointing to the PORTABILITY section.)

Comment: Thanks a bunch man! i'd have never thought that that was the cause. Good thing I printed the contents of document, eh? :)

Comment: Noting "Most of this behavior", raises a question: what aspect is @rici assuming is not documented?  (The action of carriage return is mentioned toward the end of the [waddch manual page](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addch.3x.html), so *that* cannot be it).

Comment: @ThomasDickey: Fair enough. I suppose I should have read all the way through to the end before the snipe. Fixed with thanks.